# Who else was on the council?

Tags: the-legend-of-korra

We see in Legend of Korra that Republic City has a ['United Republic City Council'](http://avatar.wikia.com/wiki/United_Republic_Council) in a flashback we see it being chaired by a member from each nation, except water which has a representative from the North and South tribe.

Who else is on the council at the time of the flashback? Or do we not know?

Answer (score 4):

As far as I can tell,

- Earth: Unknown - Member
- Air: Tenzin- Current Member
- Fire: Unknown Councilmen- Member
- Water (South): Sokka- Former Member, Deceased.
- Water (North): Tarlok- Former Member, Deceased

I'm not sure about all of them but I hope this helps.

Comment: That's good! Are you saying the ones we see in the flashback as the same as in the current era?